# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument'

Tags: javascript, ssl, iframe

Ever since I have installed an SSL certificate, I have an issue with running a js targeting some information coming from an iframe.

I keep getting:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.
>   *** .ro" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

While searching the internet I found out this is a security issue that won't allow you to load files from another domain or subdomain but the thing is, I am not loading from a subdomain or a different domain. I am loading directly from the same domain/iframe.php .

This happened right after adding an SSL certificate, before that, the exact same script worked without issues.

Comment: Show us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was one of absolute vs relative url for the iframe.

I initially used the website's full url (`https://www.***.ro/iframe.php`) which made it look like trying to load a page from another domain even if it wasn't. Once I changed it to simply `../iframe.php` everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try using object and embed to simulate a iframe maybe this works

```
<object data="https://...." width="600" height="400">
    <embed src="https://...." width="600" height="400"> </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Well, I don't get the error anymore but the script won't work. I believe I have to tweak the script now since I used **'$('#getmesomenumbers').contents().find('#last');** to access the iframe

Comment: @Alin well ive helped you one step into the right direction good luck tweaking the script.

Comment: Yup, will work on it and mark the answer as soon as i can ;). have a great day!

Comment: There was another issue in fact. I've added an answer. Thank you for your help.